# Windows very very slow after system upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, lts

I've done a Ubuntu Upgrade and suddenly everything is very very slow?

What types of log files can help?  I've looked in my /var/log/ and cant seem to find any details and "top" and system monitor doesn't show any problems.  I think its maybe something with the display drivers or xwindow system?

```
cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

What can help me see what the problem might be?  My MEMORY and CPU usage seem very low but everything moves super slow?

```
    lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G84GL [Quadro FX 1700]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f4000000-f5ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f701ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say Windows....?

Comment: I'm not sure I think its something to do with the display window not being able to move around and some type of muilti-threading getting locked up?